# add delimiter to fixed-width text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to add a delimiter to a fixed-width text file.

This is what I have thus far:

```
list=[4,29,36,45,70,95,100,111,115,140,150,151,152,153,169]
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            newline = line[:4] + '|' + line[4:]
            outfile.write(newline)
outfile.close()
```

The code above inserts a pipe at the 5th byte. I'd now like to add a pipe at the next value in the list (29). I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: How is the variable ``list`` used in your code?

Comment: I don't think this does what you think it does: `line[:4]` and `line[4:]`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is what you're looking to do:

```
list=[4,29,36,45,70,95,100,111,115,140,150,151,152,153,169]
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with open('results.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            iter = 0
            prev_position = 0
            position = list[iter]
            temp = []
            while position < len(line) and iter + 1 < len(list):
                iter += 1
                temp.append(line[prev_position:position])
                prev_position = position
                position = list[iter]
            temp.append(line[prev_position:])

            temp_str = ''.join(x + "|" for x in temp)
            temp_str = temp_str[:-1]

            outfile.write(temp_str)
```

this takes an input file and inserts a `|` at the positions within the list.  This will handle cases that are smaller or larger than the values in your list.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack. Check if it works:

```
list=[4,29,36,45,70,95,100,111,115,140,150,151,152,153,169]
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            for l in list:
                newline = line[:l] + '|' + line[l:]
                outfile.write(newline)
# outfile.close() -- not needed
```

Comment: This is assuming that every line is > 169 chars long.  Also the size changes with each iteration.  You'll need to account for that.

Comment: @KronoS you are right my bad but let's see what swhit wants. Perhaps an iterator would do to get the next value from the list